# AWS Lambda access data refresh hourly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My AWS Lambda function needs to access data that is updated every hour and is going to be called very often via api. What is the most efficient and least expensive way?

The data that is already updated every hour is configured through Lambda batch, but I don't know where to store this data.

How about putting the latest data in the latest bucket of Amazon S3 every time? Or, even if there is a problem with the hot partition, how about storing it in Amazon DynamoDB because it is simple access? I considered the gateway cache, which is updated every hour, but at a cost. Please advise.

Comment: You need to describe in more detail what the data looks like. How large is it? How are you accessing it exactly (via some sort of queries, or just loading the whole thing into memory in the Lambda function for example?). Is it a hard requirement that this not cost anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned "least expensive way" I will suggest to use Amazon DynamoDB because 25GB of space is free (always not free tier). Now if your data size is more than 25GB then also you can use DynamoDB over other services like RDS or S3 that comes at a cost.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. If a lambda could access an item for an hour, would this be the best way to do it? I am concerned that it will be a hot partition.

Comment: @DK2 What do you mean by accessing for an hour? How many times are accessing it and how large is the data? I would not really bother about hot partitions because you will run out of RCU way before that. Just for comparison, a hot partition will be throttled at 3000 RCU, free tier gives you 10 RCU.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to use [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html). It is secured via IAM and is a great way to share parameters between AWS Lambda functions.

If your data is too big to store in Parameter Store, then consider storing it in Amazon S3. It is easily accessible and low-cost.

If there are problems using these services, then you could look at using databases but there is insufficient information in your question make an appropriate recommendation.